Button to run a script
I don't know if I'm too ambitious, but here is my thing:

Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-200-generic x86_64)
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2024-07-17T18:58:09

File /etc/apache2/apache2.conf : (end of file)
ServerName localhost
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .sh

File /etc/apache2/conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf :
        <IfDefine ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN>
                ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
                <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
                        AllowOverride None
                        Options +ExecCGI
                </Directory>
        </IfDefine>

In the /var/www/cgi-bin a copy a script I tested manually.
I chown www-data:www-data the /var/www and recursively
I chmod 777 the same folder and recursively (security is NOT a problem)
The script just gets a file from /var/www/dhcplog/site1.txt and edit things :
#!/bin/bash

chmod 777 -R /var/www/dhcplog/
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/dhcplog/ -R

sed 's/[$]//g' /var/www/dhcplog/site1.txt
comm --output-delimiter="$" /var/www/dhcplog/site1.txt /var/www/dhcplog/archive > /var/www/dhcplog/archive2
sort /var/www/dhcplog/archive2 > /var/www/dhcplog/archive
rm /var/www/dhcplog/archive2

The script is not supposed to show anything to webclient, i just want to edit a file in background.
I tried several options to create a button to run the script.
The last one :
<a href=”http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/archive.sh”&gt;
   Call my Shell Script</a>

<form action="cgi-bin.archive.sh" methoid="post">
        <input type=”submit” value=”Call my Shell Script”>
</form>

It 'should' run the script directly with IP/cgi-bin/archive.sh, but that only gave an error in /var/log/apache2/error :
AH01215: (8)Exec format error: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/archive.sh' failed: /var/www/cgi-bin/archive.sh
End of script output before headers: archive.sh


Please [edit] your question and show us the script. Make sure to use the formatting tools to format is as code. We can't help you debug code you don't show us. We need to see the code of the script and the HTML code you are using to trigger it.

!#? Did you mean #!?

I replace the !# for a #! but I have the same error

Does your script produce the correct output according to the CGI specification? Because the error message ("End of script output before headers") suggests it doesn't.

I tried to change the first line by #!/bin/bash, not working.
What do you mean by CGI specification, the script only change the right :
chmod 777 -R /var/www/dhcplog/
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/dhcplog/ -R
Then edit the txt file, nothing more.

You probably need to make sure your script outputs/prints some valid HTTP headers before anything else ... Maybe the bare-minimum is Content-Type like Content-Type: text/html or full headers if needs be ... Web-servers serve all sorts of content and web-browsers might rely on headers to properly display/handle the content that's why they are required.

Please make sure your question accurately describes the current situation. If you have the correct #!/bin/sh and not the wrong !#/bin/sh, then show that in the question. Also, are you expecting the script's output to be shown in the browser?

I edit the file with more accurate information. As Terdon ask, no it didn't show anything, I just want to edit a file on the server. I want the button to run the bath and then I have a link on the webpage to open the archive with my beautiful information.
